# LiDAR data denoising algorithm complexity

Tags: lidar, algorithm, lastools, noise, spatial-outliers

I want to remove outliers (noise) from LiDAR data.
Currently I'm using the same algorithm as LAStools:

> The LAStools software version 171215 implements a straightforward outlier
>     removal technique (lasnoise) based on the spatial frequency (SF) of the
>     points.As described in the documentation, for each point in the dataset,
>     a 3D structure - voxel - formed by 3x3x3 elements is generated having the
>     current point as centre. If the number of points within this voxel
>     (27 cells) is inferior to a certain threshold, the current point is
>     considered an outlier (isolated point).

The problem is even if I subdivided the original dataset into smaller files, I still end up with around 4M data points. And because the algorithm complexity is O(n²) (for each point, check if any of the points is inside the voxel), the running time explodes around 500000 data points.

How do they manage the performance aspect and is there a better way to remove outliers ?

Comment: I don't know if the algorithms are faster but PDAL is an free open source alternative https://pdal.io/stages/filters.html

Comment: Did you benchmarked that or it is just a supposition? I don't see why you think this algorithm is quadratically complex. With a spatial index it should be performed in a near linear time.

Comment: Yes I benchmarked it. What do you mean by spatial index ?